# Error when attempting to put file into hadoop hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I try to put a file into hdfs I get an error.

There is also an error in my hdfs browser saying: 
`Failed to retrieve data from /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: Server Error`

I have already tried restarting hadoop, formatting namenodes, and many other things.

hdfs dfs -put ~/map.osm /planettest

```
2019-10-23 13:19:40,728 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2019-10-23 13:19:42,575 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /planettest._COPYING_ could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:872)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:818)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2678)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:510)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1081)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
put: File /planettest._COPYING_ could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Comment: It looks like your data done is not running. Can you look at the startup logs to confirm?

Comment: where are those logs?

Comment: start here.  http://fibrevillage.com/storage/660-how-to-check-a-hadoop-cluster-healthy-status  THis says if you go to the namenode status UI: `http://<namenode>:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-datanode`  it'll tell you if all the datanodes (or in your case THE datanode) is working..  if it's not you'll know.  you can then troubleshoot that.

Comment: just out of curiosity, are you using a sandbox?

Comment: i don't think the datanode is working. no i'm not using a sandbox

Comment: do this.  `cd $HADOOP_LOG_DIR` and look for the latest log that talks about the data node.  paste it here.  If you can't find it, just try to re-initalize the datanode: `$HADOOP_HOME/bin> hdfs namenode -format -force
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin> ./start-dfs.sh
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin> ./start-yarn.sh`

Comment: @acree The namenode doesn't need formatted to fix a datanode

Comment: had similar error log , when i had less disk storage for datanode. it got resolved once i increased the disk size for datanode